# Calling PHP with jquery for a small chat widget

Tags: php, jquery

Currently I am calling a PHP script every 500 milliseconds (I want it to be a "live" chat) to get the latest chat messages and place them in the widget on the website. It all works fine but I am wondering if there's a better way to handle the message retrieving. Something like a callback when someone posts a message and only then ask PHP for new chat results.

Am I doing it the right way or are there better options.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Checkout [Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) and/or [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) (as a fallback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websockets and using something like http://pusher.com/ is a much better approach than "polling" for data.